# Error on resize or move focus on video play back - no picture sound continues

Tags: epiphany, video-player

On the epiphany browser when i watch a video on youtube it start playing OK.

If I then resize, or move mouse focus off the player or try to use the mouse to re-wind the stream to replay the last bit again the sound continues but I loose the video.

It is as if the video is going to the wrong plane on the display output.

Is anyone else seeing this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

That's https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183085. The only known solution is to update GStreamer, which seems not very likely to happen in Loki.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg gstreamer1*
```

It helped me with my videos not being played in Loki.